# Getting NodeJS to work with VS2015

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015

I have problem installing **npm packages**, I'm using *NodeJS 5.0.0*.

I have *Python 2.7.3* and *Visual Studio 2015* installed on my machine. I had a problem getting VS2015 to work with Node before, 
`error MSB4019: The imported project "...\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found`

after I fixed it by changing the required path value to `V140` *(to point to VS2015 directory)*. Now I get a this error:

```html
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not fi
nd WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid versio
n number. [c:\Users\Murhaf\Desktop\sage\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [c:\Users\Murhaf\Deskto
p\sage\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\Users\Murhaf\Desktop\sage\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate Exit status 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect this is because Node 5 includes NPM 3, which had some massive changes around how dependent node modules are installed. Can you try going back to a previous version of node and see if that fixes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work by installing Windows SDK.

First I installed Windows 10 SDK, it didn't work.

Second I installed Windows 7 SDK, it also didn't work.

lastly, I launched VS2015 uninstaller, I choice modify to add WINDOWS 8.1 SDK feature, I installed it using their VS2015 installer then it worked.

The reason in my opinion was about its registry key, but I didn't want to spend more time on it, Windows SDK 8.1 fixed the problem.